# Count of outbound API calls from Salesforce to third party

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout

Is there a way that I can get a count of how many API calls have been made FROM Salesforce TO external system? Is there any OOTB way or any appexchange tool that can give us the outbound API call count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Apex Callout Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_apexcallout.htm) from [Event Monitoring](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000339868&type=1) can give you granular details, but it may come at an extra cost. Any AppExchange App that would give you this info would have to depend on Event Monitoring as well.